# How to change property without exposing the property sheet

Tags: directshow

I have the CLSID of the property pages of an encoder. I retrieved this by querying the filter for `IID_ISpecifyPropertyPages`.

```
hr = pHauppaugeSienaEncoder->QueryInterface(IID_ISpecifyPropertyPages, (void **)&pProp);
```

I also have the array of `IUnknown`.

But how do I get access to the properties to be able to change the values? How can use these CLSIDs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Directshow filter properties C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050074/how-to-change-directshow-filter-properties-c)

Comment: Thank you Roman. Looks like I have to get the filter SDK. I am wondering if there is a workaround.

Comment: Sometimes there is a type library you can import (the DLL implementing the encoder filter) and it opens the interfaces you need.

Comment: I got the SDK, but it looks like they do not implement any interface like IAMVideoControl etc.. Instead I see in the .h that they are inheriting IDispatch. I have queried a lot of interfaces and all of them return the hr = E_NOINTERFACE.