# DirectShow filter change property (DSPACK)

Tags: delphi, directshow, dspack

I am relatively new to directshow programming, i use a directshow video compression device, using GraphEdit can change the compression settings simply by right clicking on the filter and selecting properties, there a way to do this programmatically?

I tried the VideoMediaType, but i get a single value !? how do I set all the configuration pages?

Configuration https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNyp4.png

Pins Interfaces https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRi5D.png

I am programming in Delphi 7 using DSPACK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These properties are implemented and available though certain device-specific COM interfaces. You need to contact Sigma Designs to request documentation or SDK to access them programmatically. What you are seeing on configuration screenshot is their (Sigma Designs) property page which is internally using the mentioned interfaces to set up the device. To do the same/similar from your code you need interface definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, looking better on StackOverflow I found an answer to a similar problem. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930586/how-do-i-set-the-properties-of-a-directshow-filters)